# Terms for related DB records

Tags: database, terminology, relational-database

Here's a DB schema:

users(id, name);
items(id, user, name), *user* is a foreign key
tags(item, name), *item* is a foreign key

Based on that schema:

- each *item* has one *user* (one to one relationship)
- each *item* may have multiple *tags* (one to many relationship)

Pretend you are a record from *items*.

What term would you use to refer to a record from *users*, based on your relationship? Would you call it a "one to one relative" or something else?

Similarly, what term would you use to refer to a bunch of *tags*? Would you call them "one to many relatives" or something else?

Comment: What purpose does the term serve? Are you looking for a term that identify an object's role in a relationship, like the terms "divisor" ("divides(divisor, dividend)") or "parent"?

Comment: I'm writing a class that deals with DB records. Each instance of the class is based on a single record. I need the terms for the names of a couple of methods in that class - these are methods that retrieve related records.

Comment: Does each user have only one item, or is items-to-users many-to-one?

Comment: Each *item* has one *user* but a *user* can have multiple *items*.

Comment: Are "tags" [metadata tags](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_(metadata)), like the ["database"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database) tag this very question is tagged with?

Comment: Yes, they are - exactly like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the class is specific to items, you could call the user for an item an "owner", and the tags simply the "tags".

If the class is a generic record handler (e.g. an [active record](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) or [data mapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html)), there aren't many English words that would apply. "Relative" and "relatives" are two, though they may not add much meaning to method names. There's a functional relationship between items and users, where the item is the argument/input and the user is the value/output, but these terms are poor descriptions. I suspect most any generic terms will suffer the same problem of having low descriptive power.

Taking inspiration from the term [codomain (of a function)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codomain), you could try using the prefix "co-".

In the OO world, the relationship between items and tags is an [aggregation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_diagram#Instance_Level_Relationships), which suggests that you could refer to the tags as an "aggregate" in method names.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks for taking the time! I wish I could upvote this more.

Comment: I like *owner*. I was thinking, based on that, I could use *belingings* or *possessions* for one to many items. To use the example - if *user* is an owner of *item* then *items* should be belongings of *user*. The same way *tags* should be belongings to *item*. Do you think that makes sense?

Comment: It makes a certain sense. However, "ownership" is a stronger relationship than "one-to-many" and may imply certain properties. I like ["possession"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_%28linguistics%29) (especially given the [legal difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_%28law%29)), which is a little weaker than "ownership", and the corresponding "possessor" rather than "owner".

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would say "the corresponding record".

Comment: How about if you have to differentiate *one to one* from *one to many* corresponding records?

Comment: Any chance for single worded terms? I guess it would have to be something based on a metaphor.

Comment: @Emanuil - I don't know of a word in English that denotes a "one to one" type of relationship.